# F# wake up program

Tags: f#

I have this requirement: my F# program will do daily job at 11:00AM in the morning; I turn on my PC usually on 8:00AM, since I have been busy, so I always forget to run my F# program on time.  So, I want to have a function, which can check how many seconds between now and 11:00AM, if there are 3 hours, then my program will sleep 10800 seconds, then wake up and do the job.  I know I can use Windows task scheduler for this kind of job, but this way, I will not see the output from my F# program, so I have to do this in my way:

```
let wakeup() =
    let today = DateTime.Today.ToShortDateString()
    let beignTime = DateTime.Parse(today + " 11:00:00")
    // Don’t know what to do yet!
```

For function wakeup(), I want to return an int32 number of seconds if the current time is before beginTime, if current time is later than beginTime, just return 0.

```
let seconds2Go = wakeup()
if (seconds2Go > 0) then
   Thread.Sleep(seconds2Go * 1000)
else 
   printfn "Do daily job!"
```

But I don’t have a good idea on how to write the function wakeup().
Please offer your help.
Thanks,
John

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 let wakeup () =
   let beginTime = DateTime.Today + TimeSpan(11,0,0)
   beginTime.Subtract(DateTime.Now).TotalSeconds |> int
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your brilliant code, it is short but works well.
I will use your code in my program.
Thanks again for your help!  Have a nice day!
John

Answer (score 2):

This does the trick. You'll have to stop it with CTRL+C.

```
open System
open System.Threading

let (|TimeSpan|_|) value =
  match TimeSpan.TryParse(value) with
  | true, t -> Some t
  | _ -> None

let runDaily time f =
  let time = ref <| DateTime.Today.Add(time)
  let rec loop() =
    async {
      if DateTime.Now >= !time then
        time := (!time).AddDays(1.0)
        f()
      else do! Async.Sleep(1000)
      return! loop()
    }
  use cts = new CancellationTokenSource()
  Console.CancelKeyPress.Add(fun args -> cts.Cancel(); args.Cancel <- true)
  try Async.RunSynchronously(loop(), cancellationToken = cts.Token)
  with :? OperationCanceledException -> ()

[<EntryPoint>]
let main args = 
  match args with
  | [|TimeSpan time|] -> 
    runDaily time (fun () ->
      //TODO: program logic
    )
    0
  | _ -> eprintfn "Usage: program.exe time"; 1
```

Usage

```
program.exe 11:00 //run every day at 11AM
```

Comment: Hello,
Thank you very much for your code, which is not easy for me to understand.
I did a little modification in the calling part, so it is easy for me to debug it using VS2010 IDE.


    let nearFuture = new TimeSpan(22, 30, 00)
    runAt nearFuture (fun () -> printfn "Do daily job!" )

    printfn "Done!"

When I set up interval about mintues in the future, in debug mode, I can not see anything, if I let it run without debug, even before the time is up, I see a lot of "Do daily job!", it seems the program trigger the job before the time.  But may be I don't totally understand your logic.

Comment: You're right. There were a few bugs, which I fixed. The code is correct now.

Comment: Hello,
Thank you very much, your code is not easy for me to understand.
I believe Bluepixy's code is better to use.
But thanks for your help too.
Have a nice day!

Comment: This is a complete program. All you have to do is fill in your logic at 'TODO'. Otherwise, it just works. Bluepixy's answer just shows you how to compute time until wake-up, but you have to do the rest.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you jut use the Windows Scheuler to run the program at 11:00?

Comment: Hi,
As I said, if I use task scheduler, I can not see the output for my program, which is very important.  Therefore, using Windows task scheduler is not possible!

Comment: @JohnJohn the correct method is saving to a log file and then using Windows Scheduler.

Comment: Oops, missed that. In Windows 7 the task scheduler can run tasks under your credentials only when you are logged in. This means the process has access to your desktop and can open windows.

Answer (score 1):

```
let wakeup () = 11.0*60.0*60.0 - (DateTime.Now - DateTime.Today).TotalSeconds |> int
```

Comment: Hello,
Thank you very much, your code also works and it is even shorter.
However, I believe Bluepixy's code is easier to under stand.
But thanks for your help too.
Have a nice day!